# Spring Boot and dependency for spring-security-jwt

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm migrating a Spring Boot project from boot 1.5.x to 2.0.x.

In the 1.5.x project I see that the following dependency is being used:

```
dependencies {

  ...
  compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt")
  ...
}
```

The version of the `spring-security-jwt` is managed by Spring and I can verify that [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.14.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L170). Namely:

```
<spring-security-jwt.version>1.0.9.RELEASE</spring-security-jwt.version>
```

The same dependency fails to resolve when I move to Boot 2 because it is no longer managed by Spring. I can verify that [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml)...

Is this a bug or it is removed and included in another lib? Somehow I can't find clues in the docs... Shall I manage the version manually now?

Comment: i used  org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.9.RELEASE version in spring boot 2. got no problem

Comment: Yeah, it seems that there is no problem... I'm just getting nervous when I see explicit versioning in my gradle files :-) Thus I wonder if the lib is moved somewhere or they skipped it from the Boot2 dependencies for some reason.

Comment: @LachezarBalev did you come up with something better in the end?   I see you approved the answer, but it doesn't tell us how to get a JWT library!

Comment: Well, I still use org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.9.RELEASE :( It was really cheap to do so, I'm not very proud but it works perfectly OK for me so far (Spring 2.0.+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring-security-jwt` (and OAuth as well I guess) are now obsolete. Spring Security 5 added that support to the core library instead of an extension of the framework.

See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/labels/JWT-JOSE) for a list of tickets related to the core JWT and OAuth support.

So in short you don't need that dependency anymore, although if you have custom filters and functionality build around that it would require using different classes/packages and features.